# Does there exist a pair $(i,j)$ such that $x_{i}(1-x_{j})$ and $x_{j}(1-x_{i})$ are not greater than $\frac{1}{4\cos^{2}\frac{\pi}{n+1}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\in[0,1]$. Do there always exist $i,j$, $1\le i<j\le n$,
such that both $x_{i}(1-x_{j})$ and $x_{j}(1-x_{i})$ do not exceed $\frac{1}{4\cos^{2}\frac{\pi}{n+1}}$?

Comment: Some context please.

Comment: I myself do not understand something here, for each pair of numbers $0 \le x<y \le 1$  such $x(1-y) \le \frac{1}{4}$ and $lim\frac{1}{4\cos^{2}\frac{\pi}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Where did you get this problem from ?

Comment: School's local contest